# GitLab: What is the purpose for using developer role?

Tags: git, gitlab

I've noticed in `master` branch of my project `push` is prohibited for `developer` role by default.
[image]

I wonder what is the reason to have a `developer` role in this case? I mean a `developer` which have no access to push, how can submit his/her changes into project?

In such configuration, should `developer` push their changes to other branches and then project `maintainer` apply changes to master branch or there are some other typical methods for this?

Comment: Was my answer helpful or do you have more doubts about this question?

Comment: @AbdelilahElAissaoui Yes, it was helpful. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because developers push to their own branches or to a develop branch. The master branch, in many occasions, is used for pushing only production code, and not every developer should be able to push to it, just the project managers (maintainers).

An example is a developer that pushes his changes to his branch and once he has finished the changes, he creates a merge request that a maintainer will merge.